# Spring controller maps to anything under a given address

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring controller that I want to handle mapping for anything under "/location" like "/location/Seattle" for a website and return the appropriate web page. Here is what I have currently

```
@Controller
public class WeatherController {
    @RequestMapping("/location/?")
    public String getWeatherData() throws Exception {
        return "weather";
    }
}
```

How can I do this? If I am going about it the wrong way please tell me. Right now I just get an error when trying to access anything besides "/location".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class should look like this.

```
@Controller
public class WeatherController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/location/{city}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getWeatherData(@PathVariable("city") String city){
        // implement your logic in here using city variable
        return "weather";
    }
```